# The XRM Toolbox Connection Wizard throws an Error 2

Tags: dynamics-365, xrmtoolbox

When I enter the credentials and it successfully passes 2-Factor I receive an error.  This is what is in the error log.

Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Information 8  4/26/2023 7:32:29 PM  Found 3 Org(s)
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Information 8  4/26/2023 7:32:29 PM  Looking for Organization = xxxx in the results from CRM's Discovery server list.
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Error  2 4/26/2023 7:32:29 PM  Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM
Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Error  2 4/26/2023 7:32:29 PM  Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM
Source  : Not Provided
Method  : Not Provided
Date    : 4/26/2023
Time    : 7:32:29 PM
Error   : Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM
Stack Trace : Not Provided

This is a trial environment, I do not know if there is a limitation because of that.

Comment: Can you access the environment via browser ?